# inserting records from one table to another in oracle

Tags: oracle, insert

My problem is, i have two table namely enq_tab and feed_back_tab. i need to insert some columns from enq_tab into feed_back_tab and some columns are from a webpage ie, a jsp...

ex: enq_tab: enq_id,name,email,mobile,address,enq_date are columns;
    feed_back_tab:enq_id,name,email,mobile,address,enq_date,feed_back,comments,suggestions are columns

here i will get the feed_back,comments, suggestions from the JSP  , and remaining columns from the enq_tab based on enq_id, which already present in database.

anybody help me with some suggestions..

Thank in advance..

Answer (score 7):

I think you can do this way.

```
insert into table1(COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4)
select col1,col2,jspvaribalevalue1,jspvariblevalue2 from table2
```

Comment: One should always specify the columns inserting into - what happens if a column is added to `table1`?  The insert will suddenly fail.

Comment: ofcourse that is basic I forgot to mention thanks i AM EDITING